# Is it possible to assign a String variable the absolute path of a File?

Tags: java, string, file, dynamic

I am wondering if it is possible to assign a String Variable the path of the file? If Yes, then is it possible to update the File Dynamically?
I am trying to create Files dynamically (which I am able to do so), but I want to link these dynamically created files to a String variable. 
Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
File dir = new File("Data");
        if(!dir.exists()){
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        String filename = "file1";
        File tagfile = new File(dir, filename+".txt");
        if(!tagfile.exists()){
            tagfile.createNewFile();
        }
        System.out.println("Path : " +tagfile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: You mean `File.getAbsolutePath()`?

Comment: Every time the path changes, you have to change the String as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to do that:

```
File file = new File("C:\\testfolder\\test.cfg");
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

This is what javadoc says about the getAbsolutePath API:

> **getAbsolutePath**
>
> public String getAbsolutePath() Returns the absolute pathname string
>   of this abstract pathname. If this abstract pathname is already
>   absolute, then the pathname string is simply returned as if by the
>   getPath() method. If this abstract pathname is the empty abstract
>   pathname then the pathname string of the current user directory, which
>   is named by the system property user.dir, is returned. Otherwise this
>   pathname is resolved in a system-dependent way. On UNIX systems, a
>   relative pathname is made absolute by resolving it against the current
>   user directory. On Microsoft Windows systems, a relative pathname is
>   made absolute by resolving it against the current directory of the
>   drive named by the pathname, if any; if not, it is resolved against
>   the current user directory.
>
> Returns: The absolute pathname string denoting the same file or
>   directory as this abstract pathname

Comment: Thanks.. I am working on it.. But I will try this method right away and check if it works.. :) Thanks again..

Comment: you already had the absolute path to start with. try this with a relative path ...

Comment: @Juned Ahsan.. this will work very much fine if it for a single file, but is it possible that I can do the same for any number of files?

Comment: @Spoiler Yes you can just create a new file reference or use the same reference and re-initialize for different files. Here is what I mean :  File file = new File("C:\\testfolder\\test.cfg");
  String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
  file = new File("test1.cfg");
  absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
  
  // or do in a loop, depending on your need

Comment: @spoiler If it has solved your problem, then you can upvote/accept the answer so that others can be benefited.

Comment: @JunedAhsan Done :) I hope you can help me later as well.. as I am pretty much new to Java..

Comment: @spoiler The whole Stackoverflow community is there to help you as long as you exhibit that you put some effort before asking. Good luck with your learning on java, it is surely an interesting language.

Answer (score 3):

```
String s = new File("xyz.txt").getAbsolutePath();
```

or

```
String s = new File("xyz.txt").getCanonicalPath();
```

Both of the above assign (in my case) `c:\dev\xyz.txt` to the string `s`.

Comment: if xyz is a relative path like ../xyz.txt this wont print the system path

Comment: @tgkprog in the case of `new File("../xyz.txt").getAbsolutePath()`, it will return (in my case) `c:\dev\..\xyz.txt`, whereas `new File("../xyz.txt").getCanonicalPath()` will return `c:\xyz.txt`. Both work, choose whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

To get the full system path windows or linux

```
public static void main(String []args){
    String path = "../p.txt";//works on windows or linux, assumes you are not in root folder
    java.io.File pa1 = new java.io.File (path);
    String s = null;
    try {
        s = pa1.getCanonicalFile().toString();

        System.out.println("path " + s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("bad path " + path);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Prints out full path like c:\projects\file\p.txt